# Is there a way to set the dock height in fixed pixels?

Tags: macos, dock

I want to set the dock size to 40 pixels.

Is there anyway to do it in Yosemite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dock height is delineated by the size of the icons on the Dock, called the tilesize.

To calculate the tilesize for a Dock height of 40 pixels (80 pixels on my Retina display):

[image]

You can set the tilesize with the following command, replacing '29' with the size of icon you desire.

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock tilesize -int 29 && killall -HUP Dock
```

Comment: When I try to verify with script: tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
 set dock_dimensions to size in list 1
 set dock_width to item 1 of dock_dimensions
 set dock_height to item 2 of dock_dimensions
end tell
I get 43, not 40.

Comment: @Koray I measured the Dock using [xScope](http://xscopeapp.com). Do you have a Retina display? Feel free to adjust the formula based on results for the AppleScript, but the formula works fine for measurements obtained with xScope.